# Does $\deg_k F(-D)/F = \deg_k D$ hold for effective divisors $D$ and coherent, torsion-free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $F$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator{\F}{\mathcal{F}}\DeclareMathOperator{\o}{\mathcal{O}}$Let $X$ be a reduced, pure dimensional, projective curve over some field $k$. 
Let $\F$ be a coherent and torsion-free $\o_X$-module. 
Let $D$ be a non-zero effective Cartier divisor on $X$ with regular global section $s$ which defines the embedding $\F \stackrel{\cdot s}{\to} \F \otimes \o_X(-D)$. We write $\F(-D) := \F \otimes_{\o_X} \o_X(-D)$.

> Do we have $$\dim_k H^0(X,\F(-D)/\F) = \deg_k D\quad ?$$

This is obviously true for invertible $\F$. But what about the more general case of coherent and torsion-free sheaves?

Comment: In the case $\mathcal F = \mathcal O_X^r$, do we not get $(\mathrm{deg}_k D)^r$ instead?

Comment: In addition to @MarcPaul comment, I think what you write $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ is usually written as $\mathcal{O}(D)$.

Comment: @MarcPaul  Could you elaborate that? So is the formula rather $\deg \F (D)/\F = (\deg D)^{\text{rank} \F} $?

Comment: @Mohan You write $\mathcal{O}(D)$ for the integral ideal sheaf corresponding to $D$? In the books I've read they (for instance Görtz/Wdhorn and Liu) it is denoted by $\mathcal{O}(-D)$. Or am I mistaken something? Do you mean $\mathcal{O}(D) \supset \mathcal{O}$ or $\mathcal{O}(D) \subset \mathcal{O}$?

Comment: The former. $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ is the ideal sheaf of $D$, so you have this a subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}$ and dually, you have $\mathcal{O}\subset\mathcal{O}(D)$.